# Android Studio is being stuck on preparing the plugin

Tags: android-studio, plugins

I am currently facing a serious problem while installing a new plugin on Android Studio. The IDE cannot be installing the plugin and being stuck on it. Can you please tell me how to fix this or delete the plugin before running Android Studio? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I faced the same problem.. Just go to C://users/YOURUSER/.AndrodiStudio1.5/config/plugin/ and then delete the folder of importer plugin. now restart your Android Studio IDE I hope it works. in my case it worked. For more information here is the link. https://youtu.be/be_P-yHpVvo

Comment: can you tell me what is the path of the plugin in android studio 3.0.1 ? I searched under the plugins folder. But could not find the Android Drawable Importer file

Comment: You can find folder in C://users/YOURUSER/.AndrodiStudio<your_version>/config/plugin/